# A Groovy Election

Tags: community-challenge, groovy

Implementing the [July 2015 Community Challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5414/july-2015-community-challenge) seemed relevant considering it is [election time](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/1).

I decided to go with the strategy pattern as this can be implemented in many different ways. I did my own implementation of this first, and then later also added a "PascalElection" strategy, as that code was translated and adapted from [a Pascal implementation](http://www.dia.govt.nz/diawebsite.NSF/Files/meekm/%24file/meekm.pdf) (not included for review here)

Overview of code:

- **ElectionStrategy**: Interface for the Strategy Pattern
- **Election**: Class to hold data about the votes and nominees. Also contains a static method to perform an election.
- **ElectionResult**: (static class within `Election`) Represents the result of an election.
- **CandidateState**: (static class within `Election`) Represents several states a candidate can be in (my strategy only uses three of them, the PascalElection strategy uses all of them).
- **SimonElection**: My own implementation of the election strategy
- **Round**: As the STV voting system is an iterative one, this represents a single 'round' in the voting. This can be used to plot a graph over the results. (The code to produce the graphs is not included in this post)

This project is also available on GitHub: **[Zomis/StackSTV](https://github.com/Zomis/StackSTV)**

#### Example graphs showing election results:

My strategy:

[image: Graph with Simon's strategy]

The pascal strategy:

[image: Graph with another strategy]

#### Code

ElectionStrategy:

```
interface ElectionStrategy {

    Election.ElectionResult elect(Election election)

}
```

Election:

```
class Election {

    final List<Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<>()
    final List<Vote> votes = new ArrayList<>()
    int availablePositions
    int maxChoices

    private Election(int availablePositions) {
        this.availablePositions = availablePositions
    }

    void addVote(Vote vote) {
        this.votes << vote
        this.maxChoices = Math.max(maxChoices, vote.preferences.length)
    }

    void addCandidate(String name) {
        this.candidates.add(new Candidate(name: name))
    }

    double calculateQuota(double excess) {
        (votes.size() - excess) / (availablePositions + 1)
    }

    static class ElectionResult {
        List<Round> rounds
        List<Candidate> candidateResults

        List<Candidate> getCandidates(CandidateState state) {
            candidateResults.stream()
                .filter({it.state == state})
                .collect(Collectors.toList())
        }
    }

    ElectionResult elect(ElectionStrategy strategy) {
        strategy.elect(this)
    }

    static enum CandidateState {
        HOPEFUL, EXCLUDED, ALMOST, NEWLY_ELECTED, ELECTED
    }

    @ToString(includeNames = true, includePackage = false)
    static class Candidate {
        String name
        double weighting = 1
        double votes
        CandidateState state = CandidateState.HOPEFUL

        Candidate copy() {
            new Candidate(name: name, weighting: weighting, votes: votes, state: state)
        }
    }

    @ToString
    static class Vote {
        int numVotes
        Candidate[] preferences

        static Vote fromLine(String line, Election election) {
            String[] data = line.split()
            Vote vote = new Vote()
            vote.numVotes = data[0] as int
            int candidateVotes = data.length - 2
            vote.preferences = new Candidate[candidateVotes]
            for (int i = 0; i < vote.preferences.length; i++) {
                int candidate = data[i + 1] as int
                if (candidate > 0) {
                    vote.preferences[i] = election.candidates.get(candidate - 1)
                }
            }
            vote
        }

        void distribute(Round round) {
            double remaining = numVotes
            int choiceIndex = 0
            preferences.eachWithIndex { Candidate entry, int i ->
                if (entry) {
                    double myScore = remaining * entry.weighting
                    entry.votes += myScore
                    remaining -= myScore
                    round.usedVotes[choiceIndex++] += myScore
                }
            }
            round.excess += remaining
        }
    }

    static final ElectionResult fromURL(URL url, ElectionStrategy strategy) {
        BufferedReader reader = url.newReader()
        String[] head = reader.readLine().split()
        int candidates = head[0] as int
        Election stv = new Election(head[1] as int)
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates; i++) {
            stv.addCandidate("Candidate $i") // use a temporary name at first. real names are at the end of the file
        }

        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != '0') {
            Vote vote = Vote.fromLine(line, stv)
            stv.addVote(vote)
            line = reader.readLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < candidates; i++) {
            String name = reader.readLine()
            stv.candidates.get(i).name = name
        }
        stv.elect(strategy)
    }

}
```

SimonElection:

```
class SimonElection implements ElectionStrategy {

    @Override
    Election.ElectionResult elect(Election election) {
        List<Round> rounds = new ArrayList<>()

        int electedCount = 0
        int roundsCount = 0
        double previousExcess = 0
        while (electedCount < election.availablePositions) {
            Round round = new Round(roundsCount, election.maxChoices)
            rounds << round
            double roundQuota = election.calculateQuota(previousExcess)
            roundsCount++
            round.quota = roundQuota
            election.candidates*.votes = 0
            election.votes*.distribute(round)
            List<Election.Candidate> elected = election.candidates.stream()
                    .filter({candidate -> candidate.votes > roundQuota})
                    .collect(Collectors.toList())
            elected.each {
                if (it.state != Election.CandidateState.ELECTED) {
                    electedCount++
                }
                it.state = Election.CandidateState.ELECTED
                it.weighting *= roundQuota / it.votes
            }
            if (elected.isEmpty()) {
                Election.Candidate loser = election.candidates.stream()
                        .filter({it.state == Election.CandidateState.HOPEFUL})
                        .min(Comparator.comparingDouble({it.votes})).get()
                loser.state = Election.CandidateState.EXCLUDED
                loser.weighting = 0
            }
            round.candidates = election.candidates.collect {it.copy()}
            previousExcess = round.excess
        }
        new Election.ElectionResult(rounds: rounds, candidateResults: election.candidates)
    }

}
```

Round:

```
@ToString
class Round {

    int round
    List<Election.Candidate> candidates = new ArrayList<>()
    double quota
    double[] usedVotes
    double excess

    Round(int round, int maxChoices) {
        this.round = round
        this.usedVotes = new double[maxChoices]
    }

}
```

#### Running the code

Tests are available on the GitHub repository, I am currently only running the code in a test, [using election data from the most recent Stack Overflow election](https://github.com/Zomis/StackSTV/blob/master/src/test/resources/stackoverflow-com-2015-election-results.blt)

#### Primary Concerns

I'm mostly interested in the way I'm using Groovy, and what *Groovy* things I could do instead of, or in addition to(?), using Java 8. Should I use some Java stuff instead of some Groovy stuff, or should I use more Groovy instead of Java?

Any other comments welcome.

Comment: I started Groovy-fying in a fork right here: https://github.com/emmanuelrosa/StackSTV

Comment: hmm... this is strange.... when I now test-run the election data, Mat's Mug was the third one to be elected and I become the fourth. If I change the election to only require three candidates, it says that I would have been the third and then Mat's Mug wouldn't have been elected. Is there a weird bug in my code?

Comment: I relied on the existing tests and they passed by the time I was done making changes. Which revision are you referring to?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I'm not refering to any specific revision and I'm not blaming you. I just found this a bit strange. I don't know what the real result should be from changing the election to only three candidates.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Being biased toward Groovy, I say do more Groovy stuff :)

There are a number of things you can do to make your code more *Grooooooovy*.

## *def* is your friend

The *def* keyword makes it a cinch to declare variables and it makes your declarations easier on the eyes.

```
// Eeewwww
String s1 = 'hello'
double d1 = Math.floor(10.34)
ArrayList<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>()
l1.add(1)
l1.add(2)
l1.add(3)

// Much better.
def s2 = 'hello'
def d2 = Math.floor(10.34)
def l2 = [1, 2, 3]

// It's all the same
assert s1 == s2  // == calls me.equals(other)
assert s1.is(s2) // me.is(other) is Java's reference equality
assert d1 == d2
assert l1 == l2

assert s1.class == s2.class
assert d1.class == d2.class
assert l1.class == l2.class
```

The code above also demonstrates that Groovy determines [identity](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_identity_operator) differently than Java. Also notice that primitives are auto-boxed. In fact, Groovy doesn't have primitives. Everything is an *Object*.

## *for* loops are basically pointless...

In Groovy code *for loops* are rare because there are much better ways of accomplishing the same thing.

```
// This is the same...
for (int i = 0; i < candidates; i++) {
    String name = reader.readLine()
    stv.candidates.get(i).name = name
}

// ...as this, which uses Number.times(Closure)...
candidates.times {
    String name = reader.readLine()
    stv.candidates.get(i).name = name
}

// ...and as this, which uses Range.each{Closure).
(0..<candidates).each {
    String name = reader.readLine()
    stv.candidates.get(i).name = name
}
```

Not only are these constructs pleasant to work with, they eliminate the possibility of handling the incrementation incorrectly. If it can't be touched, it can't be broken.

## ...and so are Java Streams

Groovy enhances Java Collections in such a powerful way that it makes Java 8 Streams look like Fortran *(as long as you don't need the laziness provided by Java 8 Streams)*.

### Java 8 Streams

```
candidateResults.stream()
    .filter({it.state == state})
    .collect(Collectors.toList())

election.candidates.stream()
    .filter({candidate -> candidate.votes > roundQuota})
    .collect(Collectors.toList())

election.candidates.stream()
    .filter({it.state == Election.CandidateState.HOPEFUL})
    .min(Comparator.comparingDouble({it.votes})).get()
```

### the Groovy way

```
candidateResults.findAll {it.state == state}

election.candidates
    .findAll {candidate -> candidate.votes > roundQuota}

election.candidates
    .findAll {it.state == Election.CandidateState.HOPEFUL}
    .min {it.votes}
```

## multiple classes per file

You can place multiple Groovy classes in the same *.groovy file. No more static inner classes :)

## roll your own enhancements

Just as Groovy enhances Java through its [GDK](http://www.groovy-lang.org/gdk.html), you can enhance Java and Groovy classes through [meta-programming](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_metaprogramming). Here's an example of an enhancement I made to *Election.fromURL()*:

### before

```
/* Iterates through two sections of the file.
 * The first section is handled with the 'while loop',
 * and the second in the 'for loop'
 */
while (line != '0') {
    Vote vote = Vote.fromLine(line, stv)
    stv.addVote(vote)
    line = reader.readLine()
}

for (int i = 0; i < candidates; i++) {
    String name = reader.readLine()
    stv.candidates.get(i).name = name
}
```

### after

```
/* Also iterates through two sections of the file,
 * but by using an Iterator.while(Closure condition) method
 * added through meta-programming.
 *
 * The first section is handled with the 'while()/call() loop',
 * and the second in the 'upto() loop'
 */
use(IteratorCategory) {
    reader.iterator().while { line -> line != '0' }.call { line ->
        stv << Vote.fromLine(line, stv)
    }.upto(candidates) { line, i -> 
        stv.candidates.get(i).name = line 
    }
}
```

I created this construct because it makes it easier to see the intention of the code.

### explanation

The added method *Iterator.while(Closure)* expects a *Closure* which when called returns a value that can be evaluated by the [Groovy Truth](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/groovy-latest/html/documentation/#_the_groovy_truth). The value the *Closure* returns is used to determine whether to continue iterating or not.

The *Iterator.while(Closure)* method returns yet another *Closure*. This *Closure* initiates the iteration when called. The *Closure* expects yet a third *Closure*, which is called with each element provided by the iterator. Until iteration aborts.

Finally, when the iteration completes, the *Iterator* is returned, ready for additional iterating.

*Iterator.while(Closure)* (and *Iterator.upto(Integer, Closure)*) are made possible by Groovy's meta-programming. In this case, implemented by the Groovy Category shown below:

```
package net.zomis.meta

/*
 * Adds useful methods to Iterator.
 */
@groovy.lang.Category(Iterator)
class IteratorCategory {

    /*
     * Returns a Closure which iterates while the condition Closure 
     * evaluates to true. The returned Closure expects another Closure, 
     * an action closure, as its single argument.
     * This 'action' Closure is called during each iteration and is passed 
     * the Iterator.next()value. 
     * When the iteration is complete, the Iterator is returned.
     *
     * Example usage: 
     * use(IteratorCategory) {
     *   def iter = reader.iterator().while { it != 'end' }.call { println it }
     * }
     *
     * @param condition Closure to evaluate on each iteration.
     * @return a Closure
     */
    Closure 'while'(Closure condition) {
        {Iterator iter, Closure closure ->
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                def it = iter.next()

                if(condition(it)) {
                    closure(it)
                } else {
                    break
                }
            }

            return iter
        }.curry(this)
    }

    /*
     * Similar to Number.upto(Number, Closure), executes the Closure
     * UP TO a specified number of times. However, instead of returning
     * the Closure's return value, it returns the Iterator where
     * it left off.
     *
     * Example usage:
     * use(IteratorCategory) {
     *   def iter = reader.iterator().upto(5) {it, i -> println "$i - $it" }
     * }
     *
     * @param to number of times to iterate
     * @param closure to execute. Called with Iterator.next() and index.
     * @return Iterator
     */
    Iterator upto(int to, Closure closure) {
        int i = 0

        while(this.hasNext() && i < to) {
            closure this.next(), i
            i++
        }

        return this
    }
}
```

## all done

I hope this helps you make your Groovy code more... Groooovy.

Check out most of StackSTV already Groovy-fied right [here](https://github.com/emmanuelrosa/StackSTV/tree/emmanuel).